# Data recovery after sudo rm -rf /* on ext4

Tags: data-recovery, ubuntu-10.10, ext4

I sent the following command to my friend:

```
sudo rm -rf /*
```

He launched it. Does someone know how to recover data after deleting from `ext4` on Ubuntu 10.10?

Comment: Restore from backup. He does keep backups, doesn't he?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by searching on google you have some choices:

- http://tjworld.net/wiki/Linux/Ext4Undelete
- http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

so you may want to try one of those, or refine a bit the search

Comment: there is also testdisk. that's saved me a few times. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk